# Email not send if we use g-suite gmail id

Tags: c#, email

> Error: System.IO.IOException:
>   connection:  A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time,  or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.Unable to read data from the transport

I am using G- Suite account id for sending mail.i posted my code.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["SenderMail"]);
            mail.To.Add(ToEmailId);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = "" + mailBody;
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(_configuration["SMTPServer"], int.Parse(_configuration["SmtpPortNumber"]));
            //smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_configuration["SenderMail"], _configuration["SenderPassword"]);
             smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Have you  authorized 3rd party app to use gmail smpt server?

Comment: no.i don't use any third party app

Comment: @IgorMytyuk judging by the error it looks like it's failing before it even gets to that stage

Comment: @arulpushpam The error says it can't connect to the mail server. It sounds like maybe you specified the wrong server and/or port name. We can't see what settings you have used. Either that or there is a firewall blocking you. Have you checked online to find the correct SMTP settings to use for Gmail with SSL? They are not necessarily the standard ones.

Comment: @ADyson i have used "SMTPServer": "smtp.gmail.com",  "SmtpPortNumber": "587"

Comment: I think this is no firewall issue. Because i am able to log-in the g-suite id which I used sender id here

Comment: Logging in through the website (assuming that's what you mean) will use a different port. So yes there could still be a firewall issue. Are you running this code from  inside a company/school/college network?

Comment: Anyway, if you're using SSL (as per your code) you should be using port 465, not 587. This is documented in a lot of places online, including https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en . 587 is for TLS connections. That's why I asked if you had checked it.

Comment: @arulpushpam Have you set up 2-step-verification with OTP?

Comment: @JayNaz Nope.which type of verification you are asking?